# Formatting a xmlrpcmsg array

Tags: php, arrays, xml-rpc

I have the following array

```
  Array ( [value] => Array ( [mf_account] => xxxxx [mf_username] => xxxx [mf_password] => xxxx [as_user_id-int] => e [page-int] => d [page_size-int] => x [get_campaign] => Submit [form_build_id] => form-w1vXG5j2hEeKjKYGomZjuwxWlXqbrGg5tG4ph81J3Xk [form_token] => 9onu89rRyvEWWVtSJpAUw4Ko81sitmo9BpbqtoVD110 [form_id] => messagefocus_settings_all_campaign ) )
```

I need this array to be formatted so that it's suitable for xmlrpc_client

If I hard code the array like the following it works

```
 $msg = new xmlrpcmsg(
  "campaign.all",
  array(
    new xmlrpcval(
      array(
        "as_user_id"=> new xmlrpcval('122', "int"),
        "page"=> new xmlrpcval('33', "int"),
        "page_size"=> new xmlrpcval('23', "int"),
      ),"struct"
    )
  )
);
```

Unfortunately I have too many forms to hard code handlers for all of them so I would really like to have one function that can loop through an array that has not yet been formatted and parses the values as required.

So far I have tried this but I am just getting errors back.

```
  //Please ignore all parts of the if statement except the final else
  $temp = new xmlrpcmsg();
  foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 'get_campaign'){
      break;
    }elseif ($key == 'mf_account' || $key == 'mf_username' || $key == 'mf_password') {
      $credentials[$key] = $value; 
    }else{
      //this is where my problems occurs
      $keyValues = split('-', $key);
      $temp[$keyValues[0]] => new xmlrpcval($value, $keyValues[1]);
    }
  }
```

For me debugging this is made doubly awkward because I have to develop it inside drupal and the form is processed through ajax meaning the only error that I'm getting back is

```
  An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
  HTTP Result Code: 500
  Debugging information follows.
  Path: /system/ajax
  StatusText: Internal Server Error
  ResponseText:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing the first declaration of $temp the errors disappeared.

```
 $temp = new xmlrpcmsg();
```

Then I just kept the loop as it was

```
  //$temp = new xmlrpcmsg();
  foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 'get_campaign'){
      break;
  }elseif ($key == 'mf_account' || $key == 'mf_username' || $key == 'mf_password') {
    $credentials[$key] = $value; 
  }else{
    //this is where my problems occurs
    $keyValues = split('-', $key);
    $temp[$keyValues[0]] => new xmlrpcval($value, $keyValues[1]);
  }
}
```

Then I formatted the message like this

```
 $temp = new xmlrpcmsg("campaign.all", array( new xmlrpcval($temp), "struct"));
```